# I want to pop from viewContoller to parent viewController with out code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, popviewcontroller

I want to pop from `childviewContoller` to `parentviewController` in storyboard with out write any code in file with the help segue.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What is `childviewContoller` and `parentviewController`? Is it in the `UINavigationController`? Or modal? Sounds like you wish to create an app without writing a code

Comment: swift or objective c?

Comment: Check this link : 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: You should implement [unwind Segue concept](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) , just need to add an empty method to your parent view controller.

Comment: when i try to implement `unwindsegue`  not call segue method of viewcontroller.m file

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a button on your child view (potentially in a nav bar or anywhere else on the page). I your storyboard, control drag from the button on the child view, to the parent view. In the pop up, choose your action segue (standard slide in slide out would be the Show segue).

If you choose present modally as your segue, then you can change the Transition on the left to not animate. This give the segue a blunt but removal feel for the child segue.

Hope this helped